Rapspberry Pi Camera module 3 connected but not working?
a@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-still -o test.jpg
[0:26:36.745682188] [3662]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:313 libcamera v0.3.0+65-6ddd79b5
[0:26:36.843226382] [3665]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:40 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:26:36.848344591] [3665]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:446 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media2 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:26:36.848456778] [3665]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1104 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Made X/EGL preview window
Mode selection for 1296:972:12:P
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,640x480/0 - Score: 3296
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1296x972/0 - Score: 1000
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1920x1080/0 - Score: 1349.67
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,2592x1944/0 - Score: 1567
Stream configuration adjusted
[0:26:37.601437792] [3662]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420 (1) 1296x972-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[0:26:37.602062425] [3665]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:621 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 20
Aborted

Same error with below command btw
libcamera-hello

System info, which is just updated/upgraded.
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"

The hardware is ok since I just had Octopi running, and the camera was working fine. So it should be a software problem?

Are you connecting to your Pi via ssh?

@CoderMike yes, SSH and VNC

don't think ssh will work because the preview window can't be displayed. VNC should work. Can you try directly with a screen, keyboard and mouse?

@CoderMike yeah I did, same result.
